# UTF-32 support in Ubuntu Terminal?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal, unicode

In Ubuntu 18.04 default Terminal, I go to the main menu and select "Terminal" -> "Set Character Encoding" I only see in the Unicode sublist only UTF-8.

Is it possible to have also [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) and [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32)? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Terminal emulation requires an ASCII compatible encoding, which UTF-32 is not. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/448745 for explanation.

That being said, nothing stops an *application* that runs inside the terminal (e.g. text editor) to read and write files encoded in UTF-32. These apps just have to internally convert it back and forth between UTF-32 and UTF-8 in order to display it in the terminal, and to interpret the keypresses arriving from the terminal.

Comment: I am writing an application in Rust which uses emoji, on the new Windows Terminal (Preview) I have no issues, but also on Windows for example CMD does not support them. Is there any other terminal in Ubuntu which I might use which supports UTF-16 and UTF-32?

Comment: I did not talk about any terminal emulator in particular. The _very concept_ of terminal emulation is incompatible with these encodings. The encoding nowadays every terminal emulator uses is UTF-8. You should also use this encoding.

Comment: Then how can this Windows Terminal (Preview) have no issues at all with this encoding? 

Comment: Maybe askubuntu is not the best forum for this question. Windows Terminal seems to be the union of the Windows console world and the Unix terminal emulation world, I'm pretty sure UTF-32, if works at all, can only work for the former type of behavior. If you are on Linux and want to display emojis, UTF-8 is what you need.

Comment: My bad, I assumed that since I'm seeing weird symbols in Ubuntu terminal, the problem was the encoding. Maybe the emoji I'm trying to display are actually UTF-8 compatible. Which would change my question to: why aren't they displayed correctly then?

Comment: "Maybe the emoji I'm trying to display are actually UTF-8 compatible." I'm sorry to say but this sentence proves that you lack the basic understanding of Unicode and UTF-x. There are no "UTF-8 compatible" vs. "UTF-8 incompatible" (or what?) emojis. Everything that's representable in Unicode is representable in UTF-8. It's impossible to answer your latest question ("why aren't they displayed correctly") since you haven't given any data point at all. Please open a new question, showing what you _exactly_ do, how it appears on the screen, vs. what you expect to appear.

Comment: Also please read what "XY problem" means, you've fallen to that by asking the wrong question (and even making wrong assumptions) in the first place instead of asking about your actual problem.

Comment: Fair enough. In case you're still willing to answer, the emoji I'm not able to display in Ubuntu terminal are these: ⚫⚪. As far as I can see, they might not be correctly displayed even here.

Comment: Some of these display for me in gnome-terminal on Ubuntu 19.10, some don't. Probably just missing from the font. (Absolutely nothing to do with UTF-32.)